# Bug in gcc 4.7? or not, I'm not sure so I ask here

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

in this code snippet:

```
template<class T, int Min, int Max>
class Range
{
    const T min_ = Min; // works without const

    T max_ = Max;

};
```

I'm getting the error

> non static const member in class without ctor

but this is irrelevant if I'm initializing it in a class. Should that be logged as a bug?

Comment: You're not getting an error, you're getting a **warning** from `-Wuninitialized` and maybe you're using `-Werror`. It's important to tell the difference.  Please report a bug to GCC's bugzilla.

Comment: N.B. when you get spurious warnings that you've turned into errors with `-Werror` you should stop using `-Werror`.  I assumed that was obvious but it seems to be a common problem on SO.

Comment: @JonathanWakely No! That's what `-Wno-error=uninitialized` is for (or `-Wno-uninitialized` if you don't even want a warning). Stopping using `-Werror` is too blunt a hammer.

Comment: `-Werror` is usually too blunt a hammer in the first place, I use it to turn _on_ individual errors, not turn them off.  The fact this question exists is testament to the fact it's too blunt a hammer, as the OP seems unaware of the difference between errors and warnings. Enable lots of warnings (and **fix** them, don't ignore them!) and use `-Werror=xxx` to turn selected ones into fatal errors. Don't just wash away the distinction betwen warnings and errors.

Comment: @Jonathan : As someone who frequents compiler-specific forums in addition to SO, I can assure you that peoples' confusion between warnings and errors are orthogonal to `-Werror` and its effects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The implicit constructor includes those initializers, so the error doesn't occur. §12.1/6:

> The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer (12.6.2) and an empty compound-statement. If that user-written default constructor would be ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

and 12.6.2/8:

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or base class is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no ctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> — if the entity is a non-static data member that has a brace-or-equal-initializer, the entity is initialized as specified in 8.5;

Comment: @smallB yes. …… Need mawr chars …… edit: i tested and like Jonathan, works for me with `const` uncommented. Without `-std=c++11`, the error is completely different. So something else is up.

Comment: I have c++11 on, so what's going on? Could it be that the distro I got (from STL (the little funny small guy who works for MS)) has a bug?

Comment: if `-Wuninitialized -Werror` is producing this error then it does seem like a bug with `-Wuninitialized` in `-std=c++11` mode. The error is completely different without `-std=c++11` because the code uses c++11 features and isn't legal c++03.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a **warning** not an error, but you are presumably using `-Werror` to turn that into an error.  You should learn to tell the difference, so you can disable the error if the warning is not useful. Warnings show the relevant warning option at the end of the line e.g. `[-Wuninitialized]` in this case, and `-Werror` causes the compiler to print:

```
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Or for `-Werror=uninitialized`

```
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
```

The warning is incorrect, so I've reported it as a bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53594